# How to use regex for jquery selector to apply some attribute to elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have an edit button which should make the contents of that table editable. The button id and class looks like this.

```
id="edit_icon_'.$row1["client_id"].'_'.$row2["project_id"].'"
class="editbtn"
```

Id depends on db values. Onclick of this button, I want all the elements of a table "just one table" to be editable..

```
<tr>
    <td id="edit_elem_'.$row2["project_id"].'_'.$row3["detail_id"].'">'.$row3["elements"].'</td>
    <td id="edit_respon_'.$row2["project_id"].'_'.$row3["detail_id"].'">'.$row3["responsibilty"].'</td>
    <td id="edit_remark_'.$row2["project_id"].'_'.$row3["detail_id"].'">'.$row3["remarks"].'</td>
</tr>
```

This is what table rows look like.. All have dynamic ids.
How should i write the selectors with regex for this to work?

```
$(document).on('click', '.editclick', function() { //entering edit mode
    var str = $(this).attr("id");              // edit_icon_1_124
    var cid = str.replace(/^\D+|\D.*$/g, "");  // 1
    var pid = num = str.replace(/.*\D/g, "");  // 124
    $('').each(function(){                 //  #edit_*_pid_* -expected, *-wildcard
        $(this).attr('contenteditable','true'); 
    });
});
```

Edit: P.S. I have multiple tables generated on the same page..

Comment: Don't make so complicated ids. Use a class on the elements and give them some data attributes.

Comment: The table I have shown is just a snippet. The page contains several tables getting generated which will have ids or classes differeing by the variable i append it with from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need REGEX for that.
You can use `data-` attribute to store the id that the edit button is intended to edit.

The button:

```
<button class='editclick' data-pid="124" data-did="1">Edit</td>
```

The Table (add class for every `did` and `pid`):

```
<tr>
    <td id="edit_elem_'.$row2["project_id"].'_'.$row3["detail_id"].'" class="p'.$row2["project_id"].' d'.$row3["detail_id"].'">'.$row3["elements"].'</td>
    <td id="edit_respon_'.$row2["project_id"].'_'.$row3["detail_id"].'" class="p'.$row2["project_id"].' d'.$row3["detail_id"].'">'.$row3["responsibilty"].'</td>
    <td id="edit_remark_'.$row2["project_id"].'_'.$row3["detail_id"].'" class="p'.$row2["project_id"].' d'.$row3["detail_id"].'">'.$row3["remarks"].'</td>
</tr>
```

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.editclick', function() { //entering edit mode
    var cid = $(this).data('did');  // 1
    var pid = num = $(this).data('pid')  // 124
    $("td.d"+did+".p"+pid).attr('contenteditable','true');
});
```

Comment: @VPR the code above works even with multiple tables. Are you aware of how event delegates work in JavaScript?

Comment: @YaronU. Works like charm.